# Does this correctly combine two unsigned 32-bit integers into one unsigned 64-bit integer in C++?

Tags: c++

Does this correctly combine two unsigned 32-bit integers into one unsigned 64-bit integer in C++?

```
std::uint32_t a = ...
std::uint32_t b = ...
std::uint64_t result = ((std::uint64_t)a << 32) | (std::uint64_t)b)
```

Is this code valid for all the unsigned integer values of a & b?

Actually, I want unique result values for all possible unsigned integer values of a & b. The aim is to keep the size/length of the result minimal (in this case, we can bind it in 64 bit).

Comment: did you mean `uint32_t a` and `b` likewise?

Comment: @SouravGhosh If he meant `uint32_t` then I don't think this will work. So probably he chose `uint64_t` deliberately.

Comment: a must have 64 bits for `a<<32` to work correctly.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I corrected the code. previously, I just copied from my code.

Comment: The cast of a to `uint64_t` is necessary; you don't need to cast `b` though it is harmless.

Comment: @NewGuy: As it happened your edit didn't invalide any answers. But when your question is whether the code is correct, i.e. there's something you don't understand about it, then please don't edit the substance of the question after answers have been posted. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: instead of the ungood & verbose casts, just write `32ULL`. :-)

Comment: In C is better to use something like this: `res=(uint64_t)a << 32 | b` or `res=a; res<<=32; res|=b;`. In this way `a` and `b` may be `uint32_t` types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it works as you'd expect (if they are really unsigned).

Comment: Lacking other information the natural interpretation is that `uint32_t` is the one from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf agreed. Still, it's important to emphasize it when using bitwise operators, so I'm leaving it in my answer.

Answer (score -4):

Another method:

```
uint32_t a = xxx;
uint32_t b = xxx;
uint64_t result;
uint32_t * p = (uint32_t *)&result;
p[0] = b;
p[1] = a;
```

Or maybe better:

```
union
{
  uint32_t b;
  uint32_t a;
  uint64_t res;
} u3264;
u3264 u;
u.a = xxx;
u.b = yyy;
// 64 bit result in u.res
```

Comment: If you want to break the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: Yes, it is not portable. But is alternative way :)

Comment: The union example doesn't break aliasing but still makes the code endianess-dependent. It is buggy btw you need `uint32_t a[2]`. Anyway, why come up with alternatives that are worse than what the OP already got? That's not helpful.

Comment: I think first method (with pointer) is faster than `( a << 32 ) | b`.

Comment: Also note that in the currently proposed union, all three members overlay each other. You'd want a `struct` containing the `a` and `b` in order. Add a `static_assert` about the sizes to rule out silly compilers.

Comment: @i486 That's just speculation and pre-mature optimization. I very much doubt that pointer arithmetic will beat bitwise operators in terms of performance on any CPU. Particularly since a modern compiler will optimize either version code into something optimal.